# Can my app load only the games installed on users device?

Tags: android, android-activity

I wan that my app should show a list of games installed on user device. Is it possible to that?
One way I think is that I will tell the user to create a folder on desktop suppose named "gamesforXYZapp". Now is it possible that my app will search for this folder and show the games put in that folder in my app?
Is there any other way?

Comment: If you have a list of the common game package names, you can easily get a list of all the installed apps then add only the apps that match your package names to your list.

Comment: If you mean a folder in the launcher, it would depend on if the launcher exports folder contents somehow to other interested apps.  I can't really see why a launcher would, but then don't immediately see major security reasons why it would be improper for one to do so.

Answer (score 0):

In Android, you cannot set your app as `"Game Type"`  so you cannot filter applications by this category.

I think, a solution to this would be to find all games packages from Google Play and put that list in your app and frequently update it. It needs uninterrupted internet connection so that you could send found apps list to server and server will return back games from that list. So, you need to write server code for that.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of 'All Games' on the Platform (like A--C does), you could use the PackageManager to determine which apps are installed on the users device, and then match that list to the 'All Games' list.

This might look something like this:

```
        List<String> allGames = //list of all games on device - not sure where you get this
        PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
        List<ApplicationInfo> appsList;
        appsList = new ArrayList<ApplicationInfo>();
        appsList = packageManager.getInstalledApplications(0);

        Iterator<ApplicationInfo> it = appsList.iterator();

        while (it.hasNext()) {
                if (appName != null) {
                        ApplicationInfo value = (ApplicationInfo) it.next();
                        if (value != null) {
                                String appName2 = value.packageName;
                                if (appName2 != null) {
                                        // Check if this app is in the 'All Games' list
                                        if (allGames.contains(appName2) {
                                                // This is a game
                                        }

                                }
                        }
        }
```